# Math behind common geometry shape drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, drawing

While reading the Core Graphics guide on Apple Dev library web site. I encountered a code snippet looks like the following

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat size = 20;
double r = 0.8 * size / 2;
double theta = 2 * M_PI * (2.0 / 5.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, size / 2, size / 2);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, r);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, r * sin(i * theta), r * cos(i * theta));
}

CGContextClosePath(context);
```

The above code will draw a perfect star. The question is, I know average geometry and trigonometry, but where do we know such a geometry drawing way? it is just by experience and reading a lot, or is there a specific topic one should study?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general math algorithms and not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rex says, this is a trivial application of trig/polar coordinates. If you don't understand it, you need to go back and study trig more.

I would say you should have at a minimum a strong understanding of high school level geometry, algebra 2, and trigonometry (These days in the US they seem to cover trig in "Precalculus").

If you want to do 3D graphics then you should also study matrix math. Those things should give you 90% of what you'll need.

Calculus is cool, and I really liked it, but I can honestly say I've never used it in my 30+ years of software development. About the only time I've used it is in trying to understand the more arcane aspects of fractal mathematics.

Comment: So, what you are suggesting, is to re-sharpen my high school math including geometry, trig, algebra 2, and matrix math (like linear algebra) to get familiar with such things?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

Comment: You might also want to pick up a book on computer graphics. That will show you how to apply those math skills to these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thank you. If you would like to recommend a specific book it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial application of polar coordinates, possibly with some vector mathematics thrown in (though it just helps it to be clearer; it's not really necessary).  One will learn these things in trigonometry, in some cases, or calculus if not.

It is really hard to predict which bits of math you might need for any particular programming problem, which is why computer science majors typically require a year of calculus plus a course or two of discrete mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The angle from one vertex to the next of a regular pentagon is

```
2 * M_PI * (1.0 / 5.0).
```

By using twice this angle in

```
double theta = 2 * M_PI * (2.0 / 5.0);
```

the lines drawn will always skip one vertex, leading to the well-known star pattern. You can experiment with a heptagon, where the elementary angle is

```
2 * M_PI * (1.0 / 7.0),
```

and skipping 1, 2 or 3 vertices. Try to find out why this does not work that simply for a hexagon.